# Is it possible to modify a WordPress REST API built-in response field?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rest

In my WordPress installation, I want to add a prefix to our post titles, accessed via REST API.

In particular, I invoke the `/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` endpoint, which gives back:

```
//....
"title": {
  "rendered": "A Title"
},
//....
```

My intention is to add a prefix each time the REST API is invoked, in all post titles. Something like:

```
//....
"title": {
  "rendered": "[TEST] A Title"
},
//....
```

My sense is that I should add a filter regarding REST endpoint invocation. I also considered [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/modifying-responses/), however I do not want to add a new field or metadata, just modify the existing one.
Is this possible somehow?

Comment: You should create your own custom endpoint and block the default ones - it will be less of a headache, trust me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way, but it's kind of hacky.

The controllers/route handlers are kind of rigid and `WP_REST_Posts_Controller` uses `get_posts()` and `WP_Query`, so there is no sensible way I know of.

But you could use the [`rest_request_after_callbacks`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_request_after_callbacks/) filter used in [`WP_REST_Server::respond_to_request`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_server/respond_to_request/).

You could do it like this:

```php
add_filter(
    'rest_request_after_callbacks',
    function( $response, array $handler, \WP_REST_Request $request ) {
        if ( is_get_posts_request( $request ) ) {
            mutate_get_posts_response( $response );
        }
        return $response;
    },
    10,
    3
);

function is_get_posts_request( \WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    return '/wp/v2/posts' === $request->get_route()
        && 'GET' === $request->get_method();
}

function mutate_get_posts_response( $response ) {
    if ( ! ( $response instanceof \WP_REST_Response ) ) {
        return;
    }
    $data = array_map(
        'prefix_post_response',
        $response->get_data()
    );
    $response->set_data( $data );
}

function prefix_post_response( array $post ) {
    if ( isset( $post['title']['rendered'] ) ) {
        $post['title']['rendered'] = '[TEST] ' . $post['title']['rendered'];
    }
    return $post;
}
```

For every route, you would have to transform the response. Luckily, the responses follow the same schema.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you don't want to create your own "custom" endpoint:

I would keep the request you get, as this is in JSON Format. then maybe use the json_decode which makes an array of the response.

You could loop through the array and edit what you would like to edit, before outputting it.

Would that suffice?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I want to do this on server-side, not at the point served. It is necessary that I change the format on the endpoint.